# Every time I connect to wifi,it gets disconnected automatically and says "(2) active connection failed before it was initialized"

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I am having ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. I am new to Linux,Whenever I open my system and connect to wifi after some seconds it automatically gets disconnected and says 
"(2) active connection failed before it was initialized". It never reconnects until I restart, once restarted this process repeats. I am unable to use wifi. Anyone please help.

In response to @waltinator

i did what you said, since i am new user therefore i am facing a lot of problem in dealing with log messages. I am pasting few log messages, i hope you can help me – Praveen Ojha

```
Jul 28 00:52:51 praveen-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK wpa_supplicant[991]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1 
Jul 28 00:52:52 praveen-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK wpa_supplicant[991]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1 
Jul 28 00:52:53 praveen-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK wpa_supplicant[991]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1 
Jul 28 00:52:54 praveen-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK wpa_supplicant[991]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
```

when i disconnect wifi it says,

```
Jul 28 00:59:01 praveen-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK NetworkManager[848]: <warn> [1501183741.5063] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation 
Jul 28 00:59:01 praveen-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK NetworkManager[848]: <info> [1501183741.5065] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found') [50 120 53]
```

Comment: Watch the logs! In a terminal window, type the command `journalctl --follow`. Then try to connect your WiFi, and see what gets logged.

Comment: @waltinator i did what you said, since i am new user therefore i am facing a lot of problem in dealing with log messages. I am pasting few log messages, i hope you can help me

Comment: Jul 28 00:52:51 praveen-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK wpa_supplicant[991]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Jul 28 00:52:52 praveen-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK wpa_supplicant[991]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Jul 28 00:52:53 praveen-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK wpa_supplicant[991]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
Jul 28 00:52:54 praveen-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK wpa_supplicant[991]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1

Comment: @waltinator after connecting to wifi it says this above message

Comment: when i disconnect wifi it says,Jul 28 00:59:01 praveen-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK NetworkManager[848]: <warn>  [1501183741.5063] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Jul 28 00:59:01 praveen-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK NetworkManager[848]: <info>  [1501183741.5065] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found') [50 120 53]

Comment: Do not use Comments to post log messages - you can't do multiline formatting in comments. Rather,  Edit https://askubuntu.com/posts/940242/edit your question, add the messages, and format them with the `{}` button. I will move these messages up, for you, just this once. It will take a while, as I'll have to get my changes voted on.

Comment: After formatting, 2 points leap out: Repeated `CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED` mesages don't give information; and `state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found')` means the WiFi Access point is not called what you typed or it's down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suffered from the same problem.
I installed the drivers of my corresponding Wireless interface.
Type `sudo lshw -c network` and look in description of your wireless interface.See your product and vendor.
Install the proper driver for your network card.
In my case I followed this link to download https://medium.com/@elmaxx/rtl8821ae-wifi-drivers-in-ubuntu-16-04-4c1286524afa